# A problem when Inject ajax to colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a wordpress plugin to play vedio. The developer has long gone. Now the play vedio button not working. From Firebug I can see the code works till bpl_split_response(response); Firebug says it's not defined. I checked ajax file that comes with the plugin, there isn't anything about "bpl_split_response". Would anybody point me where else to check the problem?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    var j = jQuery;
    j("a.link-play").live('click',
        function() {

            var link = j(this).attr('id')
            link = link.split('-');

            j.post( ajaxurl, {
                action: 'link_lightbox',
                'cookie': encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
                'link_id': link[2]
            },
            function(response)
            {
                var rs = bpl_split_response(response);

                if ( rs[0] >= 1 ) {
                    j.fn.colorbox({
                        html: rs[1],
                        maxWidth: '90%',
                        maxHeight: '90%'
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bpl_split_response` is a function that must have been defined in some js file which is not getting included anymore in the page. That file may have been removed or the function has been deleted.

This function is not part of the ajax response. It works on the response. Therefore you would need to find that piece of code or rewrite it if possible.

Good luck with that :)

Comment: Thanks! I just checked, the ajax response has results of 1 and -1 , so, this function is to pick the +1. Thanks very much!